# updating higher level widget state from lower level widget

Tags: flutter, dart

I am working on a flutter app, and I created a widget that gives me a dropdown button from 0-99 in increments of .25.  I am able to update the state of this individual widget, but when I put this widget below another widget, I am unsure of how to update the higher level widget's state from the lower level widget.  Here is my lower level widget:

```
class DropdownList extends StatefulWidget {


 @override
  _DropdownListState createState() => _DropdownListState();
}

class _DropdownListState extends State<DropdownList> {
  String selected;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    List<String> doubleList =
        List<String>.generate(393, (int index) => '${index * .25 + 1}');
    List<DropdownMenuItem> menuItemList = doubleList
        .map((val) => DropdownMenuItem(value: val, child: Text(val)))
        .toList();

    return DropdownButton(
      value: selected,
      onChanged: (val) => setState(() => selected = val),
      items: menuItemList,
    );
  }
}
```

The higher level widget that this widget is under is as follows.  I would like to update _value2 on change:

```
class Choices extends StatefulWidget {
  Choices({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _ChoicesState createState() => _ChoicesState();
}

class _ChoicesState extends State<Choices> {
  String _value;
  String _value2;
  String _value3;
  List _myActivities = [];
  String _myActivitiesResult = '';
  bool display = false;


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
        children:  <Widget> [
          Container(
          child: Row(
            children: <Widget>[
        DropdownList(),    //here is the lower-level widget
  ],  //end row widget
    ), //end row
  ),  //end container
], //end column widget
), //end column
),  //end body center
);  //end scaffold
  }

}
```

Thanks for your help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you look at the **provider** repository.

It allows you to share data for all children.

https://pub.dev/packages/provider

To update parent information, I recommend that you do this, but I recommend the provider.

If you use the **StatefulWidget** as a child, call it this way:

```
widget.callback (string value here);
```

If you use the **StatelessWidget** use:

```
callback (string value here);
```

Child widget

```
class DropdownList extends StatefulWidget {
final Function callback; // Add this
const DropdownList({this.callback}); // Add this

 @override
  _DropdownListState createState() => _DropdownListState();
}

    class _DropdownListState extends State<DropdownList> {
      String selected;

      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        List<String> doubleList =
            List<String>.generate(393, (int index) => '${index * .25 + 1}');
        List<DropdownMenuItem> menuItemList = doubleList
            .map((val) => DropdownMenuItem(value: val, child: Text(val)))
            .toList();

        return DropdownButton(
          value: selected,
          onChanged: (val) => setState(() => selected = val), // for example, call function here: callback(value string here);
          items: menuItemList,
        );
      }
    }
```

Widget Parent

```
class Choices extends StatefulWidget {
  Choices({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _ChoicesState createState() => _ChoicesState();
}

class _ChoicesState extends State<Choices> {
  String _value;
  String _value2;
  String _value3;
  List _myActivities = [];
  String _myActivitiesResult = '';
  bool display = false;

  //BEGIN: Add this
  _callback(String value){
   setState(() {
     this._value2 = value;
   });
  }
  //END: Add this


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
        children:  <Widget> [
          Container(
          child: Row(
            children: <Widget>[
        DropdownList(callback: _callback), // Add this
  ],  //end row widget
    ), //end row
  ),  //end container
], //end column widget
), //end column
),  //end body center
);  //end scaffold
  }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for helping out @DomingoMG!  Is there a way I can do this though or do I have to look at other ways of state management?  There's a lot going on with my app that would make my solution much easier.  Can I pass the higher level value in by reference and edit it that way?

Comment: I've been updating the code, there is a way to make a callback. From the main widget, pass the function and call it from the child.

Comment: Thanks @DomingoMG!  Let me look at it for a few minutes before I accept your answer but that's almost certainly it.  I really appreciate your help!

Comment: Hi @DomingoMG, this is it but would you mind showing me the code for the child widget.

Comment: I think I figured it out but just in case

Comment: We have created in the main widget a function called callback.

In the secondary widget, we have indicated that you will receive a function of the primary widget.

In the post, I asked him to call the function according to the type of widget he is using in the child.

Comment: It worked!  Thanks again for all your help @DomingoMG!

Comment: :), if you have any further questions, you can count on me again, regards.

Comment: Thanks!! I'll try my best to keep using stack overflow to not bother you too much but if I ever need to I'll definitely reach out!